# are equivalences in an $(\infty,1)$-category preserved under colimits

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Let $C$ be an $(\infty,1)$-category (e.g. quasicategory) having all small colimits. If $f_i:x_i \to y_i$ are equivalences in $C$ indexed by a small set $I$, is $f:=\mathrm{colim}_{i \in I} f_i$ an equivalence?

Intuitively, I think the answer is no because you can glue a bunch of contractible simplices to get a non-contractible simplex...but maybe my intuition is wrong since I might need to take homotopy colimits (which I don't really understand) to fix this.

I ask because I'm trying to find the justification for a claim  a proof on p.410 of Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, here is the relevant sentence (the definition of the category $P^K_R(C)$ I don't think is relevant for my question. The set $\mathcal{K}$ is a small collection of small simplicial sets):

[image]

My question really is, why is $\mathcal{X}$ is stable under $\mathcal{K}$-indexed colimits?

Comment: Answer to title question: yes, that's the whole point of homotopy colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sorry, but do you really mean the answer to the title question "yes"? It seems to me that if answer to the title question is "no" that's the reason we need homotopy colimits.

Comment: @yogeshmore, colimits are in infinity-categories _are_ homotopy colimits.

Comment: @Adeel oh, yes of course. Thanks! So I agree with Zhen Lin, the answer to my title question is yes, and then that also answers my latter question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, since colimits in infinity-categories are homotopy colimits.